# How to manage rewards for small delegators?

Tags: transactions, rewards, fee, transfer

What would be the best way to transfer rewards for smaller delegators? For instance for those who have delegated less than 1XTZ.

Usually their staking capital generates not so much in terms of rewards. In order to transfer them their rewards, the baker would have to spend on transaction about half of the rewards generated by them.

So what is a solution here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution is to apply the minimum payout rule. So, you will pay the delegator only when this value is reached.

For example, let `MinPayout = 0.01`, then:

```
Cycle    Reward    Debt    Payout
#n       0.004     0.004   --- 
#n+1     0.004     0.008   ---
#n+2     0.004     0.012   0.012
```

That's it =)

Comment: yes, it is a great idea. but people may expect to be paid every cycle as everybody else.

Comment: @labeo then you can leave it as a choice to them if they want half of their reward to be eaten by transaction cost. It is their decision. One detail of your T&C should precise whether the baker or the delegator should pay the transaction costs.

Comment: @labeo It's a common practice coming from the PoW mining pools. I think crypto-people not so stupid to understand that =)
Also, people use resources like https://baking-bad.org to check rewards and payouts. These resources should be able to handle the "min. payout" setting (e.g. BakingBad can do this). So people will see if some payouts are missed due to the "min. payout" setting or not.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the calculations, we advise you to use the program for the automatic distribution of awards. It reads and pays for any amount delegated to you

https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor

If you have any questions, you can contact me, I will try to help you.